# Is "ScrollWidth" property of a span not working on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, html

I have a span with some text inside it.

```
document.getElementById('span1').scrollWidth;
```

on firefox return '100' as the scrollWidth but Chrome returns only '0'. Does Chrome not support this 'scrollWidth' property? Any other browser which doesnt support the same?

Also what would be work around for this if I need to get the length of a sentence in pixels?(I keep populating 'span1' with sentences using 'innerHTML' property)

Comment: <span id="span1" style="display:block">Bhumika</span>  this when accessed using document.getElementById('span1').scrollWidth; gives the complete width of the page. This is different than the behaviour at firefox which provides the width of "bhumika" as the span's scrollWidth.

Comment: Setting the display=block;visibility=hidden wont work if done manually ..in the least it didn't for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of difference in how Firefox and Chrome respond to css and js.
[ff=Firefox, c=Chrome, sw= scrollWidth ]

Key points:

1. sw works only when the element's `display` is not `inline` and `none`.
   ff sets the `display` to `block` by default while c sets it to `inline`. 
   So you would not get sw in c. If you need the element to be hidden anyways just use:
   `visibility:hidden` without setting the `display` for both ff and c.
2. If u have set the `visibility` in c, use `style.width` of the element instead of sc. This works.

If you still want to use sc on chrome also for a hidden `span`, you could use 
@AnthonyWJones answer on

[Knowing how wide a text line will be in HTML for word wrap and other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216759/knowing-how-wide-a-text-line-will-be-in-html-for-word-wrap-and-other-application)

Worked for IE7,8,9 , FF, Chrome.

Comment: Ohk ...there is something on with the css defined in the AnthonyWJones answer that is making it work on Chrome as without it and simply noting the visibility as hidden wont work on chrome as display remains as inline. However with the css, display becomes block. No idea how it happens. Someone explain

Comment: Alright in the css provided: position:absolute is doing the trick.